# Querying for all the companies in Quandl via Python

Tags: python, quandl

Is there a way to query a certain piece of information (ex. End of the Day Stock price) and/or all information related to the financial situation of all companies that exist in the database in Quandl via Python (instead of querying for a few companies at a time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the name of all the companies, make a loop. I give you a hint:

```
for(companies in CompanyList):
    data = Quandl.get(companies)
    #then do whatever you want to do with the data!
```

If I am understanding right your question!

Comment: Do you have any idea where I could find names of all the companies on Quandl?

Comment: Even if you have all compaines, you may not be able to get it for free.

Comment: Is there a way to get the names of all the companies the data of whom can be attained for free?

Comment: I just looked into the API Documentation of Quandl. This seems to contain the answer to my question: https://www.quandl.com/docs/api?csv#dataset-list

Comment: Cool! Can you validate my answer (as it is the only one)!